# What does ‘content’ as part of a degree mean?

Tags: degree, latin

I have just received a letter of recommendation from my supervisor from two years ago, and in it, they* present me as ‘M.Art.Content’ (magister artium [?]). Searching online for various key words + content, unsurprisingly yields no good results. I know they are highly qualified in Latin, and am sure there is a reason for it.

Currently there is only one good idea (as suggested by @BryanKrause): That it might be a reference to performance, i.e. *magister artium contentus* (master of arts, satisfactory), similar to the old Norwegian system of *[laud](https://snl.no/laud)* (from Latin *laudabilis*). This makes sense. If anyone has more knowledge of how one reports a candidate’s capabilities internationally, and could elaborate on the meaning and tradition of this usage, it would be of great aid.

*Singular (unsexed) they.

Comment: Is it at all possible that this is an auto spell correction error? Otherwise I'm also mystified. What country? Norway?

Comment: Could it be that they used a generic template and forgot to replace a placeholder? something like M.Art. <insert content here>

Comment: You might have to ask them; could be related to 'contentus' but I have no idea how that would apply to a degree or what it would mean.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, Norway is correct. The letter of recommendation is ment for use outside of Norway, though.

Comment: @Erwan Yes, that could be a possibility, but that would surprise me greatly, considering them being well-known for attention to details.

Comment: @BryanKrause You might be on to something. I have edited the question to include your thought.